# Play Sound OnClick Android

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, onclick, playsound

I simply want to play a mp3 file when I click a button in android studio.

My problem is that with the 2 methods I use the sound is played but for some reason, I hear it like an extremely distorted super slow motion sound. While if I normally open the file it is ok.

!!!!!METHOD 1:

I declared:

```
SoundPool mySound;
int soungId;
```

I initialize:

```
mySound  = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
soungId = mySound.load(this, R.raw.asd,1);
```

Then is use an action listener:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mySound.play(soungId,1,1,1,0,1);
    }
});
```

!!!!!METHOD 2:

I declare:

```
MediaPlayer mp = null;
```

I use listener:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        managerOfSound();
    }
});
```

My managerOfSound mathod :

```
public void managerOfSound() {
if (mp != null) {
mp.reset();
mp.release();
}
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.www);
mp.reset();
mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the Soundpool instance of the MaxStreams maximum number (maximum number of concurrent streams) is too low

```
SoundPool mySound;
mySound  = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
```

Comment: i am just trying to stream 1 and i tried this and unfortunately it did not work

Answer (score -2):

try this,

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

// Set data source -
setDataSource("/sdcard/path_to_song");

// Play audio
mp.start();

// Pause audio
mp.pause();

// Reset mediaplayer
mp.reset();

// Get song length duration - in milliseconds
mp.getDuration();

// Get current duration - in milliseconds
mp.getCurrentDuration();

// Move song to particular second - used for Forward or Backward
mp.seekTo(positon); // position in milliseconds

// Check if song is playing or not
mp.isPlaying(); // returns true or false
```

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Comment: I followed that and it still behaves as described